# An azure machine with docker an python3

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am not sure if I am asking a right question but I am looking for a Linux redhat Azure machine with Docker and Python3 stack which would be free and available in the marketplace. Does anyone aware of such an image in Azure marketplace?

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, Azure aims to provide the pure VM images, you can install anything in the VM as you want, it depends on you. Maybe another one does not want the Docker and python3 installed in the VM.

So I suggest you just use the pure Redhat VM image to create the VM and use the VM extension or the cloud-init to provision the python3 and the Docker server in the VM. That's the right way you need to focus on.